# jQuery: Trouble deleting dynamically created content

Tags: jquery, html

Ok, so I have been stuck on this problem and I do not know why it will not work. I have created a jsfiddle of what my program is generally trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZNbm8/

my jQuery is:

```
var count = 0;
$("#add").on("click", function(){
    var html = '<div id="stuff">';
    count++;
    html += '<button class="remove" id="' + count + '">Remove</button>';
    html += '</div>';
    $( html ).insertBefore("#add");
});
$(".remove").on("click", function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

and my html is:

```
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Basically I have a button that is creating some html. This new html creates a button associated with it that should allow the user to delete that newly created entry. I do not know why this is not working though. I have searched for solutions, but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working because you are attaching the click handler to elements that don't yet exist.

If you alter your click handler slightly by using a delegate, you should be fine:

HTML:

```
<div class="parentElement">
  <button id="add">Add</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".parentElement").on("click", ".remove", function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: omg...I just realized what I did and I came back to delete this because I got it working. Felt stupid afterwards that I got the calls wrong xP Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 2):

As you are inserting the content before `#add`, just grab it's parent and add a delegated event handler with `on()` to remove the `#stuff` element, like so:

```
var count = 0;
$("#add").on("click", function(){
    count++;
    var html = '<div id="stuff_' + count + '">';
        html += '<button class="remove" id="a' + count + '">Remove</button>';
        html += '</div>';
    $( html ).insertBefore("#add");
}).parent().on('click', '.remove', function(){
    $(this).closest('[id^="stuff_"]').remove();
});
```

EDIT: fixed the ID issues !

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the delegated version of `on` for this to work

Fiddle:

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove",function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DpDYq/

Answer (score 0):

When adding dynamic elements, if you want your javacsript to effect these elements you'll need to use `.live`

```
var count = 0;
$("#add").live("click", function(){
    var html = '<div id="stuff">';
    count++;
    html += '<button class="remove" id="' + count + '">Remove</button>';
    html += '</div>';
    $( html ).insertBefore("#add");
});
$(".remove").live("click", function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZNbm8/3/

**EDIT**

AS Mentioned in the comments, `live()` is deprecated in later versions of jquery (1.7+). Do this instead:

```
var count = 0;
$('body').on('click', '#add', function(){
    var html = '<div id="stuff">';
    count++;
    html += '<button class="remove" id="' + count + '">Remove</button>';
    html += '</div>';
    $( html ).insertBefore("#add");
});
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

The above will attach the handler to all DOM elements with class "remove" or the id "add" that are descendants of DOM elements within the 'body' even if they are added in the future.

Comment: No, don't use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) it's deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 (as noted in the API reference for the method). Use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (jQuery 1.7+), or [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (jQuery < 1.7) instead.

Comment: @DavidThomas so which function should we use?

Comment: I didn't know that! Thanks @David Thomas, what do you replace it with so I can edit my answer?

Comment: as far as I have seen, on() does the same thing and people seem to use that now instead of live().

Answer (score 0):

For that use

```
$('.remove').live('click', function(event)
```

Comment: live is depreciated in 1.7 and removed from 1.9

Comment: @Eric which function should we use

Comment: You should use the delegated version of on().  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to jQuery's documentation:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers.

So you could also do it like this using `.on()`:

```
$("body").on("click", ".remove", function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/JWFgS/

Note: You can change `body` for the parent element...